# go-swagger do not validates Body in POST request

Tags: go, swagger, go-swagger

Swagger ignoring required fields in body of POST request.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Describe swaggerfile

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  title: Sample API
  description: API description in Markdown.
  version: 1.0.0
host: api.example.com
schemes:
  - http
paths:
  /users:
    post:
      operationId: UserCreate
      parameters:
        - name: body
          in: body
          required: true
          schema:
            allOf:
              - $ref: "#/definitions/ID"
              - $ref: "#/definitions/User_object"
              - type: object
                required:  # HERE! IT IS NOT WORKING
                  - ID
                  - genderCode
                  - birthDate
                  - code
      produces:
        - application/json
      consumes:
        - application/json
      responses:
        200:
          description: "OK"

definitions:
  ID:
    title: ID
    properties:
      GUID:
        type: string
        description: "ID"
        format: uuid

  User_object:
    title: User_object
    properties:
      genderCode:
        type: string
      birthDate:
        type: string
        format: date
      code:
        type: string
```

2. Generate api

> swagger generate server -f swaggerfile.yaml -t api

3. Describe single handler:

```golang
api.UserCreateHandler = operations.UserCreateHandlerFunc(func(params operations.UserCreateParams) middleware.Responder {
        return middleware.NotImplemented("MUST NOT BE PRINTED")
    })
```

4. Make a request to generated api:

> curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"foo":"bar"}' localhost:{{host}}/users

Expected result:

> 400 Bad Request

Given result:

> 501 MUST NOT BE PRINTED

Comment: If it's a bug report, you should file it in the go-swagger repository at https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger/issues.

Comment: @Helen for now it is unclear bug is it or mistake

Comment: Your API definition is correct so this is most probably a bug (or missing functionality).

Comment: BTW the issue is exist: https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger/issues/1904 .
Maybe  someone will suggest a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

My personal workaround is

```
api.UserCreateHandler = operations.UserCreateHandlerFunc(func(params operations.UserCreateParams) middleware.Responder {
        if params.Body.UserObject == (models.UserObject{}) {
            return //... your BAD REQUEST type
        }
        return middleware.NotImplemented("MUST NOT BE PRINTED")
    })
```